# PowerShell "Period" operator, what does it do?

Tags: powershell

I've been looking online for a specific answer to better help me understand how this works. In PHP we use the " . " to concatenate strings. However in powershell I see things like this:

```
    Dir | where {$_.extension -eq ".txt"} | 
    Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace “.“,”-” }
```

I can see that the "Dir" command is piped to "Where" but, I don't understand what its defining a variable for using:

```
    $_.extension
```

Is this a way of adding extra operators to a function?? I'm pretty confused. I'm getting better but, I need to know how exactly periods and the $_. work when using the cmdlets and what not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The "." call operator will send and receive variables from other scripts you have called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Powershell has very good help files included that can answer many questions.

See:

```
get-help about_operators
```

and you will find that the dot is used as both a Property dereferencing operator and a scope operator, with explanations of the use of each.

Can also see this under [about_operators on TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It's the member access operator. `$_` is a special variable (the loop variable in this case). Therefore, `$_.extension` accesses or invokes the property `extension` on `$_`.

Comment: Thank you as well, I coudln't find alot about Member Acess but it pointed me in the right direction =)

Answer (score 0):

`DIR` command is similar to `Get-ChildItem` command. The `|` is similar to `foreach` statement. The `$_` sign indicates each element in `foreach` loop. In your case, the code should get all which have `.txt` extension from some location and then rename each of those elements due to `{ $_.name –replace “.“,”-” }` rule

Comment: Actually the `dir` command ***is*** the `Get-ChildItem` command. See for your self by doing `Get-Alias -Name dir`